# Dynamic Data Masking in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, masking

Is there a solution to Dynamically Mask data at rest in SQL Server 2014. I am aware of SQL Server 2016's DMM functionality, but want an equivalent solution in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/blog/building/sql-data-mask

Comment: Check this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31418.t-sql-dynamic-data-masking.aspx